# How to view pdf in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am new in flutter. I am trying to view PDF in flutter using flutter_pdfview , pdf_viewer_plugin , syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package but I am only able to see only 1 PDF which is less than 10 kb and other pdf those are more than 10 kb then gives below error.

```
java.io.IOException: cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted.
```

Above error comes when i am using flutter_pdfview package and i case of other two package it didn't any error but unable to view PDF data.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

OR

Suggest any basic package to view PDF in flutter.

I am getting PDF file data from my golang server in string format and convert it into Unit8List and used it to view PDF.

I am trying to view PDF file in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try this alternative:**

```
PDFView.fromBytes(
  bytes: yourUint8List,
);
```

**Here is some example:**

```
Future<Uint8List> getPdfAsUint8List(String pdfFilePath) async {
  final File file = File(pdfFilePath);
  final Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  return bytes;
}
```

**How to use it:**

```
final String pdfFilePath = '/path/to/my/pdf/file.pdf';
final Uint8List pdfBytes = await getPdfAsUint8List(pdfFilePath);
```

but you need to convert it to bytes.

Comment: ok, I will check with it.

Comment: Can you please share any example of it. @Dewa Prabawa

Comment: hey just edited the answer. check it.